# create a dataframe using groupby based on condition

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe:

```
   Id       age     gender      role       marital_status      sal

   231      42        F         0          single              42K
   134      77        M         1          married             89K
   222      34        M         0          married             56K
   453      22        F         1          single              44K
   546      32        F         1          married             45K
```

i need to create a report based on gender and role where marital_status is married plus i need to add another field for percentage of married customers .

how can i do that using groupby statement.

thanks in advance

the desired output should be like:
gender           role         marital_status:                                                                       F                1             married                                                                                   M                1             married                                                                                M                0             married

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: the desired out put should be like this:

Comment: What is desired output if all values in `marital_status` are `married` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
df1 = df[df['marital_status'] == 'married'].copy()
df1['perc'] = len(df1.index) / len(df)
print (df1)
    Id  age gender  role marital_status  sal  perc
1  134   77      M     1        married  89K   0.6
2  222   34      M     0        Married  56K   0.6
4  546   32      F     1        Married  45K   0.6
```